# Can't upgrade kernal after installing Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, upgrade, kernel

A while back I set up an installation of Ubuntu 14.04.1. Part of this process, I installed Nvidia drivers from the Ubuntu Software Center. Everything went ok and I never thought anything about it until recently when I've noticed that I wasn't receiving kernel updates when running `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

After carrying out some investigation it seemed that I didn't have the linux-generic meta package installed. When I looked into the logs to see when it was removed, it was removed when the Nvidia drivers were installed.

```
Start-Date: 2014-09-21  11:56:30
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.63'
Install: fakeroot:amd64 (1.20-3ubuntu2, automatic), screen-resolution-
extra:amd64 (0.17.1, automatic), lib32gcc1:amd64 (4.9.1-0ubuntu1, 
automatic), dkms:amd64 (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5, automatic), 
libcuda1-331:amd64 (331.38-0ubuntu7.1, automatic), nvidia-settings:amd64 
(331.20-0ubuntu8, automatic), nvidia-331:amd64 (331.38-0ubuntu7.1), 
nvidia-libopencl1-331:amd64 (331.38-0ubuntu7.1, automatic), bbswitch-
dkms:amd64 (0.7-2ubuntu1, automatic), nvidia-opencl-icd-331:amd64 
(331.38-0ubuntu7.1, automatic), libfakeroot:amd64 (1.20-3ubuntu2, 
automatic), nvidia-prime:amd64 (0.6.2, automatic), libc6-i386:amd64 
(2.19-0ubuntu6.3, automatic), libvdpau1:amd64 (0.7-1, automatic)
Remove: linux-generic:amd64 (3.13.0.35.42)
End-Date: 2014-09-21  11:57:24
```

On my work's computer with an almost identical setup the same thing occurred. I was missing the linux-generic package as it was uninstalled when the Nvidia drivers were installed and I couldn't update the kernal. The only difference regarding installing the drivers between the two was on my work's machine I installed the drivers manually through apt.

Is it normal for this package to be removed when installing Nvidia drivers and can I simply install it again or will it have any negative side effects?

Regards, Ian

Comment: can you show the outputs of `uname -a` and `lsb_release -d` please.

Comment: you could also run `dpkg -l | grep linux-image` to see your installed kernel(s) you should have version 3.13.0.51.58 listed

Comment: @JoKeR On my work's PC `Linux desktop 3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 3 21:30:07 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` and `Description: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS`. My home PC has the up to date kernals installed as I have already manually reinstalled linux-generic.

Comment: @mchid Again on my work's pc `linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic linux-image-3.13.0-36-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-36-generic`

Comment: you seem to be running an old version of kernel on 14.04.2 by default it ships with `3.16.0.30` what does `apt-cache policy `linux-image-`uname -r`` tell you? remove one upper coma (apostr) at the end of uname -r

Comment: @JoKeR `linux-image-3.13.0-36-generic:
  Installed: 3.13.0-36.63
  Candidate: 3.13.0-36.63
  Version table:
 *** 3.13.0-36.63 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Answer (score 0):

That's probably just an older version of linux-generic that was updated then. The newest version is 3.13.0.51.58 and the one that was uninstalled was 3.13.0.35.42.

Run the following commands in an open terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
```

It will probably say something like "newest version is already installed". If not, you will see a list of what will install and what will uninstall if you install the package. Review this list before accepting the changes.

---

**ALSO**

You can always check to see what is installed by running the following command:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

or

```
dpkg -l | grep generic
```

and so on.

Comment: After running those commands it wants to install the latest version of the kernal as expected. It seems that both `sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic` were removed previously when i run apt-get autoremove.  Why would it remove these packages if the system relies on them to upgrade its kernal?

Comment: @IanCaunce IDK, it really shouldn't have but that doesn't even necessarily even mean they are not installed or uninstalled . . . really, how would you even be running right now without a kernel? Are you aware that you must run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to do kernel updates? Running `sudo apt-get upgrade` does not do kernel updates.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware and as far as I know the packages listed above are meta packages which always depend on the latest kernel so if they are missing/uninstalled I wont receive updates and the kernel will be locked at its current version.

Comment: @IanCaunce you're correct. Also, I checked into the linux-generic meta package and it depends on the two packages here (linux-image-generic & linux-headers-generic) which are both also metapackages. I could be wrong but I believe it is safe to install linux-generic as linux-image-generic and linux-headers-generic will remain installed which probably why autoremove would remove it. As long as those two other meta packages are installed, you should still get your kernel updates. Now, if those two got uninstalled that would be an issue and I believe that is not normally supposed to happen.

Comment: Yeah not sure what is happening to be honest. On both my work & dev machines, `linux-generic` were removed when installing the nvidia drivers via the software center and the `linux-image-generic` and `linux-headers-generic` where removed when running `apt-get autoremove`

Comment: @IanCaunce I have heard of similar issues and will keep an eye out myself. I believe when you explicitly install both those metapackages using apt-get before running autoremove the system will mark those packages as "installing previously unselected package . . . " without downloading. You can test this by running `sudo apt-get -s autoremove` and then by checking the list of apps that would uninstall to see if this would happen again or if explicitly installing has fixed this issue.